# Swift UI Live Preview Canvas not working with macOS Catalina and Xcode 11.0

Tags: xcode, swiftui, macos-catalina, live-preview

I'm running Xcode 11.0 on macOS Catalina public release (19A583). 
Opening a Swift UI file, I cannot see the "resume button" to enable Live Preview on Canvas window, even if I selected "Show editor and canvas".

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by updating Xcode to version 11.1 (11A1027) (released on the same date as Catalina public release).